# How to capture multiple values in 1 input field (a la Facebook messages)?

Tags: php, javascript, function, forms, scripting

The main example would be Facebook Messages. On the "To:" field, you can type in one letter, then it will show a search result of your friends that matches that letter. Then once you choose that friend, you can add another friend, on that same input field.

Is there a function/script that allows you to add more than 1 data on the same input field?

Comment: There is a jQuery plugin that does what you're looking for, you could grab it and figure out how it works: http://iantearle.com/projects/facelist

Comment: Thanks. I also found other resources that might be helpful if someone stumbles with this problem: 

http://thewebfellas.com/blog/2009/6/11/facebook-style-multi-select

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a function/script that allows
>   you to add more than 1 data on the
>   same input field?

Short answer, no.

If you look at the source code for the "To:" field, you realize Facebook isn't achieving this effect with only a text input.

This trick uses a div to mimic a text input, but also has a text input (with no border) within it to capture the text being typed.  Once they a match is found in the search drop down, a 'token' is inserted into the div, and the text input is shifted over.